# Passport Facebook Strategy, trigger route with AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, facebook-authentication, passport.js

The problem: 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…lhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=1527429390857121. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

If i click the link in the error i get autenticated and get back the datas in json. If i remove the clientside js router everithing works fine. But i am trying to build a SPA app.

I don't use any specific frontend framework, I use [flatiron director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) router and generate the view with handlebars.

On the clientside:

```
 var facebook = function () {
        console.log('GET /auth/facebook');

        $.ajax({
        url: '/api/auth/facebook',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false
       });
    };

// ROUTES ===============================
var routes = {
    ...
    '/auth': {
        '/facebook' : facebook,
        '/twitter' : twitter,
        '/google': google
    },
    ...
};
```

On the serverside:

```
    // send to facebook to do the authentication
    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return res.status(403).json(info);

            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.json({user: user, message: info});
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

in server.js

```
...
app.use('/api', router);
...
```

Comment: it's been a while, but did you have any luck with this? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it to server:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a cors issue:

Try the following:

`$ npm install cors`

then, in your server.js:

`var cors = require('cors');
...
app.use(cors());`

For more details on cors module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

and on cors and ajax: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I still getting the same error. If I turn of the frontend routing and hit the url directly without ajax it works like a charm.